# A minimalistic kind of read-copy-update class

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, lock-free, atomic

This is a very simple [read-copy-update (RCU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update)-inspired synchronization class:

```
#include <atomic>


template<typename T>
class RCU
{
private:

    std::atomic<T*>  curr;
    std::atomic<T*>  prev;
    std::atomic<int> readers;

public:

    RCU()
    : curr   (new T),
      prev   (nullptr),
      readers(0)
    {

    }

    ~RCU()
    {
        delete curr;
        delete prev;
    }

    void lock()
    {
        readers++;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        readers--;
    }

    T* get()
    {
        return curr.load();
    }

    T* clone()
    {
        return new T(*curr.load());
    }

    bool swap(T* t)
    {
        /* If prev is full, a swap is still pending. Clean up memory and
        abort the operation. */

        if (prev.load() != nullptr)
        {
            delete t;
            return false;
        }

        /* Store the current pointer into prev. Readers might still be reading
        through the pointer. */

        prev.store(curr);

        /* Curr contains the new proposed value. No one is reading from this
        right now. */

        curr.store(t);

        /* Spin until there are no more readers to *prev. When so, free the
        memory it points to and say goodbye. */

        while (readers.load() > 0);

        T* old = prev.load();
        prev.store(nullptr);
        delete old;

        return true;
    }
};
```

The idea is to have many reader threads that repeatedly read from some shared data, while a writer thread that rarely updates it. The writer thread takes care of cleaning up the memory when no readers are reading. Readers are "tracked" through the `lock()` and `unlock()` methods. The RCU-like class should synchronize the threads in a lock-free way.

Usage:

```
struct Data
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};


RCU<Data> rcu;


void writer_thread()  // the writer rarely runs
{
    while (true)
    {
        Data* data = rcu.clone(); 
        // modify data as needed
        data->x++; 
        data->y++;
        data->z++;
        rcu.swap(data); // Checking the return value might be useful 
    }
}


void reader_thread() 
{
    while (true)
    {
        rcu.lock();
        std::cout << rcu.get()->x << "\n"; // read from data
        rcu.unlock();
    }
}
```

Questions: does it make sense? Is it really thread-safe? Can a thread slip through the cracks somewhere, somehow?

Comment: Did you test this? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @Mast I did. I let it run for ~15 minutes without nasty surprises. So far so good.

Answer (score 4):

Serious issues with this:

1. Memory Management.
2. Not using RAII to lock/unlock

#### Memory Management

Don't pass pointers it does not indicate owners. Always wrap pointers in a smart pointer. Have a look at `std::unique_ptr`.

But for types like `Data` there is no need to use pointers. Simply use `Data` as the object type (not `Data*`).

#### RAII

Look up the concept of RAII.

A good example is `std::lock_guard` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard This shows you how to use RAII to automate the processes of lock/unlock so it is exception safe.

Comment: Good points! Regarding `Data*`: I'm using dynamic memory allocation on purpose to support non-primitive, heavy-weight types (vectors, maps, ...). Does it make any sense?

Comment: No because you can allow the person using your class decide if it is heavy weight and allow them to templatize the class specifically with a pointer type `RCU<MyHeavyWeightClass*>`.